Python's functools.lru_cache and cache not caching results of class function
I want to use lru_cache (or cache, doesn't really matter) to store the results of a very computatively intensive function of a class. However, it does not work as intended as when I included a print function to check it shows that the function is still being executed. Here is an code example :
from functools import lru_cache
class ob:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @lru_cache(maxsize = 8)
    def intensive_func(self, a, b, c):
        print("called")
        return a + b + c

This is just an example but a and b are Timestamps and c can be boolean or a string. I think that it is not related to whether the arguments are hashable. This is really strange since I have another function that also uses lru_cache and it works normally.
Thanks
I expect the lrucache to cache the results of the wrapped function but this does not work.
